# Proxying while preserving URI with mod_security2

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, mod-security

I'm using a `proxy:` action in mod_security2. I'd like to preserve the full URL of the original request, however, and it seems to be rewriting that to the url in my `proxy:` action.

So a request to http://domain.example.com/foo

hits my the below statement

`SecAction proxy:http://internal_error.example.com/`

This seems to be getting proxied to http://internal_error.example.com/, which I'd like it to be proxied to http://internal_error.example.com/foo

Is this possible?

Answer (score -2):

SecAction doesn't provide for reverse proxy I believe.

This explains how to do this in Apache:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: I'm not actually using SecAction - I'm using a SecRule with a proxy action: SecAction is a slightly easier way to illustrate. Either way though, https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#wiki-proxy indicates that proxy is a legitimate action though.

Comment: If you put the SecRule entry it would help.

Comment: The SecRule entry shoudln't matter - SecAction triggers it too. But, the SecRule I have is 
  SecdRule ARGS:Arg1 PROD \
  proxy:http://10.1.1.1/someurl/someotherurl.do